# object is not a function on stripe javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

Okay so I followed stripes tutorial for creating a custom form. And my code is as follows for the javascript. Now my credit card fields are part of a larger form and not just those fields.  it's ID is `payment-form` as you would think it would be in the code below.

My issue is that when the code runs everything works up until this line: `$form.get(0).submit();` where I receive this error: `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` I tried removing some stuff and making it: `$form.submit` but that resulted in a infinite loop.

So what do I need to do to fix this problem? What is causing this problem?

My Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Stripe.setPublishableKey('<?php echo $key; ?>');
var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="text" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    $form.find('[data-stripe]').val('');
    // and re-submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('#submit').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the id/name of the submit button to something else..aka `name="btnSubmit"`

Comment: Hmmm... That did it.... but why?

Comment: because you overrode the submit method with the name `document.formName.elementName` and `document.formName.methodName`. So when you have a method and element name with the same value, what should the browser do?